# Hiding a list element if empty css/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am filling a list up dynamically from a database, the fill up works fine, but where I have no data the list item is empty. I tried to hide the empty rows, bot my code does nothing, where should I put it if it is correct? The div is filled in from the document ready function, and after the div that contains this one, shows on `mouseclick`.

```
if ($("#results").find('.list-group-item').length() == 0){
            $(this).css('height','0px');
```

Comment: Check your console log. `length` is a property, not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to filter  empty list

```
$("#results").find('.list-group-item').filter(function() {
  return $.trim($(this).text()) == '';
}).hide()
```

Comment: Did you mean to make this a snippet, or just a code block?

Comment: Or just use https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/  `$("#results .list-group-item:emty").hide()`

Answer (score 4):

You could use the CSS3 `:empty` selector, it's cleaner:

```
#results:empty{
    display: none;
}
```

In order to `:empty` to match your list it must be completely empty, there must be no white spaces or line breaks. Like `<ul id="results"></ul>`

Or to just hide the `<li>` elements:

```
.list-group-item:empty{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to hide the whole UL, I yust want to hide the empty <li class="list-group-item"></li> element.

Comment: In that case use another selecter targeting each `<li>`, I'll update the answer.